# check depends on attribute on XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

need your help guys i've a remote xml file that has the clients' details

```
<Clients>
  <Client Name = "John">
    <id>****</id>
    <id>****</id>
    <id>****</id>

  </Client>

  <Client Name = "David">
    <id>****</id>
    <id>****</id>
    <id>****</id>

  </Client>
</Clients>
```

client will send his name with his id I would check these parameters against the above xml with two steps

first step is searching for a client Name that matchs the received name
second step is validating the received id with the list of ids for that client

if all above are found the request will be passed otherwise the request will be rejected
any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<Clients>
    <Client Name = "John">
        <id>123</id>
        <id>456</id>
        <id>789</id>
    </Client>
    <Client Name = "David">
        <id>234</id>
        <id>567</id>
        <id>890</id>
    </Client>
</Clients>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="client-name"/>
<xsl:param name="id"/>

<xsl:key name="client" match="Client" use="@Name" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('client', $client-name)/id=$id"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is called with parameters:

```
<xsl:param name="client-name">David</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="id">567</xsl:param>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>true</result>
```

With parameters:

```
<xsl:param name="client-name">Paul</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="id">567</xsl:param>
```

or:

```
<xsl:param name="client-name">David</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="id">5678</xsl:param>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>false</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

give a try to this:

```
<!-- variables to store "name" and "id" value -->
<xsl:variable name="name" select="'John'"/>
<xsl:variable name="id" select="'222'"/>

<!-- construct to match against config data -->
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(//Client[@Name=$name][id=$id])">
        <xsl:text>Access Granted...</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Access Denied!!!</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: I tried it but no lucks, the xml is remote file I have to open it and loop on it and check if there's any parameter matches with the request parameters

Comment: it always prints otherwise case

Comment: call the remote config file in the test as `document('remoteLookUp.xml')//Client[@Name=$name][id=$id]`